# Pug - how to add a span tag with a class into a mixins argument

Tags: javascript, pug

Pug template - how to add a span tag with class as interpolation into a mixins argument to surround one word so I can style it differently?

Here is the mixin from _section-headline.pug:

```
mixin section-headline(tagline, title, description, idSection)
    section.section(id=idSection)
        .container  
                .row.row--tablet-center
                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-10.col-md-12.col-lg-10
                        .headline
                            div.headline__top-line
                            p.headline__tagline=tagline
                            h1.headline__title=title
                            p.headline__description=description
```

I'm calling it into team.pug:

```
doctype html
include ./includes/global/_landing.pug
include ./includes/global/_section-headline.pug *<-- including here*
html
  head
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Team - Cerv PC</title>   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png">
  body

    - var greenText = "<span call="type--color-green">language</span>";



    +section-headline('guided by diveristy', 'We speak your '+ greenText +', 'We offer personal injury legal services in Hindi, Punjabi, and Urdu. We are happy to accommodate clients speaking other languages through the use of interpreters.', 'contact-us')
```

**So, I'm trying to place a span tag with/without text into the mixin argument so I'm making only one word green but not all. How to do this? Tried few things but nothing seems to work.**

---

I tried !{greenText} but it says false when rendered as html

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
h1.headline__title !{title}
```

instead of

```
h1.headline__title=title OR h1.headline__title=!{title}
```

Comment: did.. says false

Comment: don't use '=' only space

Comment: Okay thanks! Worked like a charm!

So, !{something} acts like a html tag?